# Finding Files by wildcard name and copy them

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I've got a program that compiles itself and generates `.exe` files in its subdirectories (such as `release_win_*` directories for every application "App1", "App2", etc.).

I'd like to find specific these `.exe` files generated and copy them to a specific `bin` location.

I have :

```
SET /p copyresult = dir /b /mydir | findstr /s /m release_win_64/*.exe
copy /y %copyresult% /bin
```

However, I have a problem. The `findstr` command seems not to accept wildcards like that. I can't get to use the wildcard. It doesn't put any result on the console.

Do you have any clue ?

**EDIT :** Added "release_win_64/*.exe" as wildcard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**"I'd like to find specific these .exe files generated and copy them to a specific bin location."**

Using a batch file:

```
cd \mydir
for /r %%a in (*.exe) do xcopy "%%a" \bin /i
```

From the command line:

```
cd \mydir
for /r %a in (*.exe) do xcopy "%a" \bin /i
```

**To match `release_win_64\*.exe` as wildcard**

Using a batch file:

```
cd \mydir
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s release_win_64\*.exe') do xcopy "%%a" \bin /i
```

From the command line:

```
cd \mydir
for /f %a in ('dir /b /s release_win_64\*.exe') do xcopy "%a" \bin /i
```

**To match `*.exe` as wildcard in any level subdirectory named `release_win_64`**

Using a batch file:

```
cd \mydir
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s *.exe ^| findstr "release_win_64"') do xcopy "%%a" \bin /i
```

From the command line:

```
cd \mydir
for /f %a in ('dir /b /s *.exe ^| findstr "release_win_64"') do xcopy "%a" \bin /i
```

See [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) for more information on `for` and `xcopy`.

Comment: This is nice. But, how can I copy with a given wildcard such as "release_win_64/*.exe" ? It seems unable to get it from the second "%%a" command. It finds them, but returns "File not Found - EXENAME.exe"

Comment: Answer updated. We need to use a different `for` command for the matching.

Comment: Does it work for you ? I get "File not Found ..." Does it search subdirectories till it find the pattern ? I've got different subdirectories in "mydir", such as "App1", "App2", and I try to get the EXEs for every app, compiled in "release_win_64"

Comment: Answer updated. Please can you stop changing your requirements

Comment: "I had to use DO XCOPY /Y "%%a" Bin" instead of "DO XCOPY "%a" \bin /i". And it works ok. Thanks